# Make return a generic object without having to make class generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a class which should return a generic ArrayList, so it would be:

```
public class MyClass{

   HashMap<String,Object> genericObjects;
   .... 
   public List<T> getAsList(String key){
       return (List<T>)genericObjects.get(key);
   }

}
```

The internal member is populated by a parser and a member of that internal hashmap can be anything, so it just makes sense to me to make it like an object. The user will have to know which kind of object it is...pretty much like ResultSet in jdbc.

So, the user would simply have to do:

```
List<String> str = myClass.getAsList("strings");
```

problem is that, in order to do so, I am forced to add a generic to class definition.
But, instantiating MyClass like this:

```
MyClass<String> myClass = new MyClass<String>();
List<String> strmyClass.getAsList("strings");
```

makes no sense as the type should have sense just for the method getAsString, which returns a generic...not for every method!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make the method generic, like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getAsList(String key){
    return (List<T>)genericObjects.get(key);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
List<String> strings = myClass.<String>getAsList("strings");
List<Integer> integers = myClass.<Integer>getAsList("integers");
```

Comment: Try `public <T> List<T> getAsList(String key){` instead.

Comment: nice it works this way! I can't do nothing about the unchecked cast warning right?

Comment: Nope. The warning is because you might do: `myClass.genericObjects.put("strings", new ArrayList<String>()); List<Integer> integers = myClass.<Integer>getAsList("strings");`

Comment: Well, you could add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` which will hide the warning.

Comment: I assumed @Phate meant fixing the warning. Yes, you can hide it.